# Rozansky-Witten class associated to the Theta Graph

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Suppose I have a holomorphic symplectic manifold, and a smooth $(1,0)$ connection on the tangent bundle which is compatible with both the complex and the symplectic structures.  Say that the associated curvature has type $(1,1)$.  Then there is a Rozansky-Witten form associated to the theta graph (the graph that looks like the letter theta).  It is a $\overline{\partial}$ closed $(0,2)$ form.  Its associated cohomology class is a Rozansky-Witten class.

Can I replace the connection with another connection with the same properties such that the Rozansky-Witten *form* is actually $d$ closed?  Is there some way to measure any obstructions to doing this?

Comment: So are you asking whether there exists a smooth (1,0) connection on TM, compatible with both the complex and symplectic structures, such that the curvature is of type (1,1) and the Rozansky-Witten form is d-closed? (Or does the replacement have to preserve other features of your original connection?)

Comment: Hi, the features that you mentioned are the ones I am interested in.  I think that I may unfortunately made two copies of myself on this website. 

Thanks,
Oren

Comment: In fact, I am actually willing to forget the curvature constraint, its o.k. with me if it has also the (2,0) part.

Comment: seems it is closed when R^{2,0}=0

Comment: Oops, I'm lost now. Would you be so kind as to edit the question to list the conditions you seek for the connection? (I'm still not sure I'll know how to proceed, but I can try!)